# How to add custom icon theme support in android launcher 3

Tags: android, android-layout, launcher, android-launcher

I am using launcher 3 source code in android. I want to change the icon background color and theme only on launcher screen but i don't know where should i change for my required issue. i go through from almost the whole code but not getting any single clue. can you help me for solving this problem. I am using launcher 3 code from here.[link](https://github.com/fookwood/Launcher3)

Comment: The whole code in here revolves around Hotseat,Launcher,Workspace check there.